# Node: Express. How do I delay a response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have defined a route. When the URL is requested, a call is made to an asynchronous function that will return a value on completion. The returned value will be my response to the get request. So, I want to delay response.get until the value is returned.

I thought about passing response to the callback function.

```
app.get("/:param", (request, response) => {
    let param = request.params.param
    search(param, response, displayResult)
})

function displayResult(info, response){
    console.log(info)
    response.end(info)
}

function search(query, response, callback) {
    request("https://www.google.co.uk", (err, response, body) => {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback("Hello there! "+query, response)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

This doesn't work. The browser gives the error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and the program crashes with the error: TypeError: response.end is not a function.

I've been looking for an answer for a while. I assume I'm going about things the wrong way.

How do I respond after my asynchronous function has returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your code carefully.

```
function search(query, response, callback) {
  request("https://www.google.co.uk", (err, response, body) => {
```

Your lambda also has a parameter named `response`. That's called ["Shadowing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer one – the ExpressJS one.

Give them a distinct name, and it will work:

```
function search(query, response, callback) {
    request("https://www.google.co.uk", (err, result, body) => {
        if (!err && result.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback("Hello there! "+query, response)
```